# Salt as been change after I put it on mysql

Tags: java, mysql, salt

I tried save the password safely on my DB.
I read about the subject and everyone recommend to use salt and save it with the password to.

So I find out this implementation:

```
private static byte[] setSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        sr.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }
```

Then I tried to save it as a bytes in MySQL

```
public static void test(byte[] salt) throws Exception{
    SQLconnect sql = new SQLconnect();
    Object[] prepString = {salt, "admin" };
    sql.runQuery("UPDATE orhalimi_cl_db.users set Salt = ? where Username = ?",
            prepString,ACTION.UPDATE);
}
```

and here is the update:

```
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(query);
            for (int i = 0; i < prepString.length; i++) {
                preparedStatement.setObject(i + 1, prepString[i]);
            }
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

And when I retrieve the salt from the DB and check for `equals` the byes are different.

I save the salt as type `binary(16)` in my DB.

And here is how I get it from the DB:

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> results;
SQLconnect sql = new SQLconnect();
Object[] prepString = {"Salt", "admin" };
results = sql.runQuery("SELECT ? from orhalimi_cl_db.users where Username = ?",
                prepString,ACTION.SELECT);
        if (results.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("empty");
            return null;
        }
return  ((String) results.get(0).get("Salt")).getBytes();
```

I know its look like I have given a lot of different parts from my code,
but it's look like I mess up the bytes on saving or retiring them from MySQL. So I gave all the info that could be relevant.

Thanks in advance.

**Answer:**

Funny thing, my problem was the fact that I used `?` on all SQL preparedStatement and not only on the value. So its looked like like `SELECT ? from orhalimi_cl_db.users who Username = ?` that turn to `SELECT 'Salt' from orhalimi_cl_db.users where Username = 'admin'`, and the answer was always salt.

Anyway I convert it to hex and base64 and it much easier now

Comment: Try saving as blob. Also, on a side note I think you need to hash your salt with your password.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to write a raw byte value to MySQL. Since byte values are signed 8-bit integers in Java, this is destined to go wrong.
You have basically two options: a) use a BLOB data type or b) encode your byte value as a Base64 string.

In case of a BLOB type (which seems to be what you tried), you need to read and write binary-safe. That also means, that you can't simply read it as String from the database and then expect the acquired bytes to be the same as those which you wrote into the database. You have to use binary streams.

I would prefer the second option. It is much safer and less complicated. Especially since you need to hash your password string together with the salt. With Base64 encoding, you can simply concatenate password and salt and then calculate the hash over the string.

**EDIT:**
Here an example how to generate a salted SHA512 hash:

```
public String getSalt() {
    String saltStr = "";
    try {
        final SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        final byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        sr.nextBytes(salt);
        saltStr = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(salt);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ignored) { }

    return saltStr;
}

public String hashPassword(String password, String salt)
{
    try {
        final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");

        // hash password and salt
        md.update(password.getBytes());
        md.update(salt.getBytes());
        final byte[] hash = md.digest();

        // convert byte array to hex string
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; ++i) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((hash[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ignored) { return ""; }
}
```

That way you can also use any other string as salt. But it is of course recommended to use a secure random number generator as in `getSalt()`.

One big advantage of using this method is that you are less dependent on Java's internal byte handling in general. With the generated hex hash and Base64 salt string you can easily recalculate the hash value outside of Java, for instance directly inside the database.

Comment: I try save, calculate it base on the salt and compare it. It's really work. Funny thing, my problem was the fact that I used `?` on all SQL preparedStatement and not only on the value. So its looked like like `SELECT 'Salt' from orhalimi_cl_db.users where Username = 'admin'` and the answer was always salt. In other words -  I hate preparedStatement.

Anyway, you help me with base64 and hex encoding so I won't need to mess up with it so much. Thank you

Comment: The ? is only a placeholder for values to make sure they are correctly sanitized. They are not used for referring to table or column names.

Answer (score 1):

This is an X-Y problem where the real question is `Is it difficult to store password hashes properly?`. The answer is yes.

I suggest you place a char(60) column on your user table and use [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Are you intentionally reinventing the wheel? Perhaps this is a learning exercise, in which case, *go get'em tiger*!